# How can I golf this Perl subroutine that does a substitution?

Tags: perl

I have the following subroutine in Perl to substitute "abc" for "xyz" in a string:

```
sub mySubst {
    my ($str) = @_;
    $str =~ s|abc|xyz|ig;
    return $str;    
}
```

It works, but seems way too verbose for Perl.  How can I tighten it up?

Comment: No... why does it seem like a joke?

Comment: I know it's short but it does not have Perlish elegance... So I wonder if I'm missing something. (e.g. it repeats the same variable 3 times)

Comment: @JoelFan With apologies to Thomas Jefferson, the ground of elegance is to be gained by inches; we must be contented to secure what we can get from time to time, and eternally press forward for what is yet to get.

Comment: AbC, ABC, abC, ... also becomes xyz. Do you want that?

Comment: @JoelFan, there's Perlish and there's readable.  If this code will never have another set of eyes on it, go for the one liner, but if you want readability, it's very nice as it is.  :D

Comment: If what you want is to definitely make a copy of the variable passed (as people assume below), make the given the substitution and return the modified copy. Then nothing is wrong with your code. The major problem I see is the name: "mySubst" <=> "s/abc/xyz/ig". And that it's probably better to set the prototype to this as `($)` or `(_)` in Perl 5.10. If you're only going to deal with the first member of a list, either communicate that in the name or prototype of the sub. Many of the compressions performed are rather useless. Some would even end up with the same op codes.

Comment: @JoelFan - there's a "can" and there's a "should". In this case, the "should" answer is "NO!" - you are not winning anything by shortening this code and losing maintainability/readability. Concise is not 100% the same as "shortest possible".

Comment: I don't really agree with the editing of the title... I did not want golf... I really do think the original is too long for what it's doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would render that subroutine more idiomatically:

```
sub mySubst {
    (my $str = shift) =~ s|abc|xyz|ig;
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Yikes! This is not idiomatic - it's just hard to read and maintain!

Comment: @DVK: It IS idiomatic.  See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=366431 for an explanation and a reference to the Perl Cookbook.  Although I should have also said that JoelFan's original snippet looks perfectly fine to me; my answer just tightens it up a bit.

Comment: @Sean - if you're sending me to the link to show that this code is valid perl - I already know that. I was merely pointing out that idiomatic - at least in my view - is a closed range (e.g. at some point, the code jumps from being merely idiomatic Perl to Perl Golf territory).

Comment: ... Closed range being "Writing C/shell/whatnot code in Perl" -> Writing idiomatic Perl by using Perl specific code to enhance power -> writing Perl Golf at which point the code becomes hard to red and unmaintainable. If you consider that rightmost area to still be  included into "idiomatic Perl", we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: As an example, your life now sucks if you want to pass >2 parameyers - you will have to either break your expression, or process @_ parameter list in disjoint points in the code. The latter is not exactly good coding.

Comment: @JoelFan - see my example above. If you wish to pass in other parameters (e.g. string to search for or to replace with), this code structure is no longer workable (at least if you wish to follow good practices and process all members of @_ in one place), whereas your original structure is just fine.

Comment: @JoelFan - also, as per Robert's answer, shift changes @_ which may be OK but might cause problems in general. Again, the question is "what is the purpose of reducing the code" - in your case, any further reducing increases readability and maintenance costs while not achieving any purpose than reducing character/line count statistics.

Comment: @DFK: To repeat, the link provides evidence that my code, and in particular the construction ($foo = something) =~ s/.../.../ is, in fact, idiomatic Perl.  And your objection to the shift() function is rather puzzling.  But fine, use $_[0] instead if you prefer.

Comment: This might be better: `sub mySubst {    (my($str) = @_) =~ s|abc|xyz|ig;    $str; }`

Answer (score 8):

**What you have is fine.**

- You pull the arguments off the @_ variable, making a copy, using a list assignment.  List assignment is an excellent way to do it (and basically the standard way.)  Using `shift` would also work, but changes @_ (may or may not be what you want.)  [There's a discussion on PerlMonks about shift vs @_](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=575918) that you might be interested in.
- You use a named variable with your search and replace.  I prefer named variables in this case, since dealing with Perl's magic variables takes care.
- Automatically working on $_ would be possible, but not having $_ auto populated makes it trickier to get right.  You'd need to do `local $_ = shift;` or `local ($_) = @_;` which doesn't add much.)
- I like it when people use an explicit `return`.  It's a warm fuzzy.
- K&R Brackets.  Good. :)
- No prototype.  Very good. :)

Go with it.  I think you're on the right track.

Comment: shift does not give you an alias.  it makes a copy just as the list assignment does.  you have aliases only when working directly with @_

Comment: you also get aliases if you re-alias @_, such as: for (@_)

Comment: I agree with you on most of your points but I still like Sean's answer, which reduces the code, at least somewhat :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for golf, and **not** production code.

```
use strict;   ## Not really required ;)
use warnings; ## Not really required ;)
sub f{local$_=pop,s/foo/bar/ig;$_}
print f 'foobarbaz';
```

Comment: Why the down votes, this is clearly not production code, but when you're trying to lessen verboseness without reason, I'm left only to assume this is a golf-esque type example. Why not indulge the questioner? This is a part of perl culture anyway.

Comment: +1 to offset downvotes, since you've clearly stated your context.

Comment: +1 If it compiles/runs it's fair game for the codegolf tag. People who don't know what golf is shouldn't vote on golfed answers.

Answer (score 3):

You could write:

```
sub mySubst { (map { s|abc|xyz|ig; $_ } "$_[0]" )[0] }
```

but unless this is an exercise in obfuscation, I would say go with what you have. Remember, you are not writing the program for the computer.

Comment: to get a string copy just use `"$_[0]"` instead of `my ...`

Comment: wow, what's with the downvotes?  this is the best answer, while still saying it's not worth doing.

Comment: Why do you need the quotes around $_[0]?  Also, you could replace that with @_

Comment: @JoelFan You need `"$_[0]"` to make a copy of `$_[0]` instead of operating directly on elements of `@_` (which are aliases to the values passed). You cannot just do `map { } @_` if (1) you want the argument not to be changed but a fresh string with substitutions to be returned and (2) if you want to be able to say `my $x = mySubst($y)` without `$x` getting assigned `1` and (3) if you want the function to operate on string literals as well (e.g. `my $x = mySubst('abc');`) For more information, look at the previous version in the edit history and my comments on the various answers here.

Comment: Wow, and the quotes are necessary to prevent the aliasing... that is subtle!!

Answer (score 1):

I think *too verbose* sounds like *not enough obfuscation* which I disagree. As for *tightening it up* I'd suggest something along the lines of:

```
sub replaceBeginningWithEnd {
    my $text = shift;
    return if not defined($text);
    $text =~ s/abc/xyz/ig;
    return $text;    
}
```

- Make names more readable
- Use conventions (ie. / as oppose to |)
- Argument checking

Comment: Perl programmers don't use camelCase much, we write our `if not` s like `unless`, and we don't typically use parens around builtins like defined.

Comment: I like PascalCase myself, but to each his own. TMTOWTDI!

Comment: How could Perl programmers not like Camel case? ;)

Answer (score 1):

No one gave the Perl idiom for this yet. This replicates the behavior of the original code by modifiying a copy:

```
  (my $new_str = $old_str) =~ s/abc/xyz/ig;
```

If I had to put that into a subroutine, which I think is kinda silly for such a simple operation, I guess that would be:

```
 sub foo { (my $s = $_[0]) =~ s/abc/xyz/ig; $s }
```

However, if I was doing something silly like this, I wouldn't make a named subroutine for it. I'd make a subroutine to make the subroutine for me so I don't need a new named sub for every possible sort of replacement:

```
 sub make_sub {
      my( $regex, $replacement ) = @_;

      # season to taste with error checking
      sub {
          (my $s = $_[0]) =~ s/$regex/$replacement/ig; $s
          };
      }

 my $replacer = make_sub( qr/abc/, 'xyz' );

 my $new = $replacer->( $string );
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the sub for? just do it like this

```
$str =~ s|abc|xyz|ig;
```

Comment: What is any sub for?  I don't want to repeat the same code in multiple places.  Also, I want something that returns the substituted string, not changes the original.

Comment: @ghostdog: This is not functionally equivalent to the code in the question. Your code modifies the string variable in-place. JoelFan's code will not modify a variable passed to the sub.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the return keyword:

```
sub mySubst {
    my ($str) = @_;
    $str =~ s|abc|xyz|ig;
    $str;    
}
```

It is also possible to use the default variable (`$_`) :

```
sub mySubst {
    local $_ = shift;  # or my starting from Perl 5.10
    s|abc|xyz|ig;
    $_;    
}
```

Comment: Although then you must localise `$_`, otherwise you will clobber the caller's `$_`.

Comment: I don't like assigning to `$_`. There is no need for it, let perl do it for you or create your own variable.

Comment: @JoelFan As of 5.10.0, `$_` can be lexicalized: http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Lexical-%24_

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that... I haven't been keeping up with 5.10!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid changing the originals, you could write

```
sub mySubst { map { (my $s=$_) =~ s|abc|xyz|ig; $s } @_ }
```

or

```
sub mySubst { my @a = @_; map { s|abc|xyz|ig; $_ } @a }
```

or to borrow from Sinan's answer, except discarding the temporary array explicitly:

```
sub mySubst { map { s|abc|xyz|ig; $_ } my(undef) = @_ }
```

but the syntax is still a little noisy. Because it uses `map`, be sure to call it in list context:

```
my($result) = mySubst $str;  # NOT my $one = mySubst $str;
```

If you expect to mostly call `mySubst` with a single argument but want to handle cases of one or more arguments, then you could write

```
sub mySubst {
  s|abc|xyz|ig for my @a = @_;
  wantarray ? @a : $a[0];
}
```

but that starts up the stuttering again.

---

If you want to update the parameter itself, use the alias semantics of Perl's subs as documented in [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> The array `@_` is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters. In particular, if an element `$_[0]` is updated, the corresponding argument is updated (or an error occurs if it is not updatable).

So you could write

```
sub mySubst { $_[0] =~ s|abc|xyz|ig }
```

or even

```
sub mySubst { map { s|abc|xyz|ig; $_ } @_ }
```

Example usage:

```
$str = "fooabcbar";
mySubst $str;
print $str, "\n";
```

Output:

```
fooxyzbar
```

Comment: I am assuming the fact that the OP's `mySubst` leaves the original string unaltered means that is a design criterion.

Comment: @Sinan Thanks and edited. JoelFan stated it explicitly in response to ghostdog74's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267312/sub-to-do-substitution-in-perl/2267390#2267390

Comment: the two versions at the top of your post assign `1` to `$x` in `my $x = mySubst($y);`

Comment: @Sinan Hence the warning to call `mySubst` in list context! :-)

Comment: Yes, I had somehow missed that warning, so +1. However, I do think this is the kind of function which should return the string in both contexts.