# How should I shorten simple substitution subroutines?

Tags: regex, substitution, perl

```
sub my_sub {
    my $str = shift;
    $str =~ s/some/regex/;
    return $str;
}
```

Five lines seems too long for such a simple subroutine. Can it be simplified, e.g. by not using an intermediary variable?

Comment: what's the problem with an extra line or so to make the code readable and maintainable? what do you think to gain?

Comment: @pavel I'm not looking for a solution that makes it unreadable and unmaintainable, but shorter. What if there's some in-place substitution that I didn't know of, for example?

Comment: Your question assumes that perl can or will inline a subroutine, which may or may not be true. I'd determine the answer to that question before trying to shorten a subroutine.

Comment: @chepner: Well, then the answer to my question would be "no".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I golf this Perl subroutine that does a substitution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267312/how-can-i-golf-this-perl-subroutine-that-does-a-substitution)

Comment: @Tim N: I still don't understand why you want shorter code. As pavel asks, what do you hope to gain?

Comment: @Borodin: Among other things, vertical space in my editor.

Comment: @Zaid: No, I don't want to impact the readability.

Comment: @TimN: Read the answers in the suggested duplicate. Even the functionality is the same!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without intermediary variable and one line shorter:

```
sub my_sub {
    $_[0] =~ s/some/regex/;
    return $_[0];
}
```

**Edit:** As @pavel noted, this will modify the original variable.

Since [Perl 5.13.2](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/pod/perl5132delta.pod#Non-destructive_substitution), there is the non-destructive modifier `/r` (for reference, see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators)), which will not modify the variable the regex operates on - this also allows to ditch another line:

```
sub my_sub {
    return $_[0] =~ s/some/regex/r;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sub my_sub {
    (my $str = shift) =~ s/some/regex/;
    $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't long for a simple substitution. It's also creating a copy of the data, substituting on that copy, and returning the modified copy while leaving the original alone. So, you'd use it like this:

```
 my $modified = my_sub( $original );
```

Some of the answers work on `$_[0]`, the first item in `@_`. This is an alias to the original data. This way, Perl doesn't have to copy the data until it knows you actually need a separate copy. When you do the substitution on the alias, you modify the original. Doing that is more like changing the original and assigning back to it:

```
 $original = my_sub( $original );
```

The question you ask, though, is to make it shorter. That's usually not a good enough reason to do anything. It's a subroutine, so let it be as long as it likes when it meets your requirements. Before you design this sort of code, figure out what your requirements are.